# In python what is the most efficient way to get the sum of values in a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I am working with opencv mats, which are numpy arrays representing images.

Is there a way to get the sum of all x,y coordinates in a frame that is 1) most efficient 2) most pythonic?

```
frame[xpos][ypos][0]   #note there are really 3 values for each pixel but i want [0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doesn't:

```
np.sum(frame[:, :, 0])
```

return what you want?